# Can PPF be withdrawn by NRI or Overseas Citizen of Indian origin

Tags: india, non-resident, retirement-plan

I want to invest in PPF, however i might move out of India permanently(read overseas citizen of indian origin) or earn NRI status. Will I be able to withdraw the money upon maturity after 15 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will be able to withdraw the money upon maturity. The PPF account cannot be extended. Under the liberalized remittance scheme an individual can repatriate back up to 1 million USD. There is some paperwork and CA certificate required.